# Pictures sometime don't load on my website

Tags: html, css, image, web

I've made a website which displays images hosted on other sites using the html src="http://......" tag, however sometimes some of the images won't load.  This appears somewhat random, and I don't think it is a problem with the links themselves.

I display a lot of images, so I am wondering if this is a common problem when trying to load many thumbnails from another site.  Is the best solution to host all the thumbnails on my own server, and if so, is there an efficient way to do this (so I don't have to manually download and link to every image)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the site owners' blessing for "hot linking" these images? It can be considered an impolite practice, which you might want to factor into your calculations.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: My code is just this repeated: <a href="..."><img alt="..." src="..."></a>.  All of the links work individually, and sometimes will load on my page (but some sometimes won't).

Comment: And yes, I have permission for what I am linking to.

Answer (score -1):

Is way better to host it on your own server.
Because if are all from other servers, you must connect to all servers and download it.
It causes worse response and increase the time required to load the page.

To the image and links downloading - I think it is possible, just go on google and try to find some advanced html page downloader. I had one and it worked directly the way you want. - can't remember the name..

(also sorry for my bad English)

Comment: Thanks, I think because I am trying to load so many pictures there is a high response time which is causing some pictures to not load.  I will look for the downloader